# Definition of the relative boundary map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

According to Hatcher (page 115), since the boundary map $\partial: C_n(X)\rightarrow C_{n-1}(X)$ takes $ C_n(A)$ to $ C_{n-1}(A)$, it induces a quotient boundary map. I am trying to reformulate this more explicitly.

To calculate the relative boundary map of a relative chain one should

- Pick any representative of the equivalence class of the relative chain in $C_n(X)$.
- Apply the ordinary boundary map $\partial:C_n(X)\rightarrow C_{n-1}(X)$.
- Project on the quotient space $C_{n-1}(X)/C_{n-1}(A)$.

The construction is independent of the choice of the equivalence class representative since the boundary map  $\partial$ on $X$ restricted to $A$ maps $C_n(A)$ to $C_{n-1}(A)$, i.e. maps chains homologous to zero in $C_n(X,A)$ to chains homologous to zero in $C_{n-1}(X,A)$.

Is this correct?

Is there any way to write the relative boundary map in terms of the boundary map on $X$ and inclusions/projections? I was thinking of $\pi\circ\partial$ where $\pi:C_n(X)\rightarrow C_n(X,A)$ is projection on the quotient, but I do not know how to compose it with a map from $C_n(X,A)$ to $C_n(X)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, let $\varphi = \pi \circ \partial : C_n(X) \to C_{n-1}(X, A)$. Since $C_n(A) \subset \ker \varphi$, by the [fundamental homomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms), $\varphi$ induces a unique homomorphism $\overline{\varphi} : C_n(X, A) \to C_{n-1}(X, A)$. This is the desired map.

Comment: I guess he means the classes $c+C_n(A)\in C_n(X,A)=C_n(X)/C_n(A)$

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed meaning a representative $\sigma\in C_n(X)$ of the equivalence class $[\sigma]\in C_n(X,A)$.

Comment: @GFR, got it. Makes sense now.